# Error with dijit.form.NumberTextBox

Tags: zend-form, dijit.form

Despite many trials and errors, I cannot get the NumberTextBox widget to work. I keep receiving this error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_NumberTextBox::numberTextBox() must be an array, null given

The odd thing is: I event tried this example straight from the ZF examples page and it failed with the same error

```
            ->addElement(
            'NumberTextBox',
            'numberbox',
            array(
                'label' => 'NumberTextBox',
                'required'  => true,
                'invalidMessage' => 'Invalid elevation.',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'min' => -20000,
                    'max' => 20000,
                    'places' => 0,
                )
            )
        )
```

So, I'm at a loss now. If someone has the time to look at the code found [here](http://pastie.org/842607), your help would be greatly appreciated. I know it's something that I'm overlooking. It always is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting decorators, make sure you change ViewHelper to DijitElement.  I ran into this problem and that was the cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comment answer helped me. that is a +1. look at the code I used below.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: try getting rid of the ',' at the end of 'places' => 0,'

Answer (score 0):

I use a base Form,

```
BaseForm extends Zend_Dojo_Form{



   public $elementDecorators = array(
            'DijitElement',
            array(
                   array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), 
                    array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element')
                 ),
              array('Label', 
                     array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-label')
                   ),
              array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), 
                    array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-row' )
                   )
         );     

   ... init(){}
   .... construct(){}
}
```

MyForm extends BaseForm{

```
constructor(){
        $this->starts = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_DateTextBox( "starts" );
        $this->starts->setLabel('Starting from')
             ->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
```

}

}

I made the source code as simple as possible, to depict the idea of what I mean.